# How to stream HD video from the web?

Tags: streaming

I'm interested if there any web server application that allows you to stream HD quality live chat without software application installed on streaming client PC. Flash Media Server allows HD streaming but it must be encoded prior to that which makes impossible to work with as any streaming client will need to install and handle their encoding software.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [Panda](http://pandastream.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your client - if it's a Mac for instance every machine of the last half-decade or so comes with quicktime which can handle HD-quality streaming straight out of the box with no additional software. There are PC equivilants too but I'm no expert, same for Linux.

As with any video application the most important first questions to ask is what are my clients and what player functionality/codecs do I **know** I can use without code distribution. Without that answer there's little we, or you, can do to move to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

HD encoding is quite CPU demanding. Still so when used only on talking heads. I guess most users do not have the HW for real time encoding and playback at the same time. This may change  in 3-6 years, but today I don't think it's a realistic idea.